# Does a non-functional whole-house humidifier affect air quality in my home?

Tags: humidifier

I installed a Honeywell Humidifier 18 years ago and it was never cleaned and stopped working 10 years ago.

Does this non working humidifier affect the quality of the air in the winter? Should we clean it or replace it altogether?

Comment: Is it a free-standing humidifier?  Or is in installed in a duct of the HVAC system?

Answer (score 1):

If you've disconnected or turned off the water there should be no ill effects from an air quality standpoint.

One consideration is slightly reduced efficiency from obstruction of airflow. I don't recall how those things interfere with the duct, but if they protrude they could introduce very slight resistance to flow with no benefit.